# How to get_comments() ordered by date and parent?

Tags: wp-query, comments, query, order

So my starting point is:

```
<?php
  $comments = get_comments(array(
            'post_id' => $post->ID,
            'status' => 'approve',
            'type'=>'comment',
            'orderby'=>'comment_date',
            'order'=>'ASC'
        )); ?>
```

And that function does exactly what I told it to do :) I receive comments ordered by comment date.

What I would like to achieve is order comments ASC by date **but** get all children comments right below parent. It seems to work this way in all themes (probably with help of `wp_list_comments` and `$reverse_children`).

How to achieve this?

Comment: You want to get them or to print them? If you want to print them, then you should use Walker class, which will prepare the hierarchy of comments based on parent field... If you want to get them, you’ll have to build that hierarchy by yourself - query will always give you just flat array...

Comment: Well, I want to print it, but I don't need info which are parent comments. I imagine that such hierarchy can be flatten to array preserving order. Think of it as max_depth=1 :)

Comment: and how will you know which comment is on which level?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż - I don't care, I want it just properly ordered